# Filter specific values in Postgres array_to_string() subquery select

Tags: postgresql, filter

I did not find an answer to this question on SO:

1. I have a column called `hashtags` with arrays of strings (e.g. `{'tree', 'house'}`)
2. I want to include this column in a selection, by concatenating array values to a single string with `;` as separator - I use `array_to_string()` function
3. **I want to filter out a specific value in this `array_to_string()`-Concatenation**

All I found was complicated subqueries, array-comparisons etc. - ideally, I require a one-liner.

Comment: All you found was *complicated subqueries, array-comparisons etc*, and that is all you will find. This results from using un-normalized data. Arrays violate 1NF thus complicating the queries. A **one-liner is just not possible** with arrays.

Comment: Thanks! Never heard of 1NF (First normal form).

Answer (score 0):

To filter out specific values, use `unnest()` in a nested subquery and filter values using `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.guid,
    array_to_string(
        (ARRAY(
            SELECT e AS hashtag 
            FROM UNNEST(t1.hashtags) AS a(e)
            WHERE e != 'house')), 
        ';') AS "tags"
FROM public.mytable AS t1
```

Taken apart:

1. `SELECT ... FROM unnest(t1.hashtags)` - the subquery that unnests array values
2. Give this subquery a name `e`, and filter out values with `WHERE e != 'house')` (will yield everything except `house`)
3. `(ARRAY())` Combine filtered values back to an array. Note the outer parentheses.
4. Apply `array_to_string()`, to concatenate values